# Pybind11 memory appears to be changed between calls

Tags: c++, pybind11

I am using pybind11 to convert scipy's csr_matrix into a C++ object through pybind11. To this end, I've defined a `Vector` class, which is converted from the numpy `data`, `indices`, and `indptr` fields.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Vector {
 public:
  T *data;
  const std::array<ssize_t, 1> shape;

  Vector() = delete;
  Vector(T *data, const std::array<ssize_t, 1> shape) : data(data), shape(shape) {};
};
```

I later register several instantiations of the class using a template function which does this.

```cpp
py::class_<Vector<T>>(m, "...Vector", py::buffer_protocol())
    .def("__init__", [](Vector<T> &v, py::array_t<T, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast> data) {
      py::buffer_info info = data.request();
      if (info.ndim != 1) throw std::invalid_argument("must be a 1d array!");
      std::array<ssize_t, 1> shape_ = {info.shape[0]};
      new(&v) Vector<T>(static_cast<T *>(info.ptr), shape_);
    })
    .def_buffer([](Vector<T> &v) -> py::buffer_info {
      return py::buffer_info(
          v.data, sizeof(T), py::format_descriptor<T>::format(), 1, v.shape, {sizeof(T)}
      );
    });
```

So the vector class works fine, however, I then define a `csr_matrix` class like so

```cpp
template<typename T>
class csr_matrix {
 public:
  Vector<T> data;
  Vector<ssize_t> indices;
  Vector<ssize_t> indptr;
  const std::array<ssize_t, 2> shape;

  csr_matrix() = delete;
  csr_matrix(Vector<T>& data, Vector<ssize_t>& indices, Vector<ssize_t>& indptr, const std::array<ssize_t, 2>& shape)
      : data(data), indices(indices), indptr(indptr), shape(shape) {}
};
```

which is then registered in the same way as `Vector` using templates, so I can register csr_matrices for floats, doubles, and ints.

```cpp
py::class_<csr_matrix<T>>(m, "...csr_matrix"))
    .def("__init__", [](
        csr_matrix<T> &matrix,
        py::array_t<T, py::array::c_style> data,
        py::array_t<ssize_t, py::array::c_style> indices,
        py::array_t<ssize_t, py::array::c_style> indptr,
        py::array_t<ssize_t, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast> shape
    ) {
      py::buffer_info data_info = data.request();
      py::buffer_info indices_info = indices.request();
      py::buffer_info indptr_info = indptr.request();

      // ... some validity checks

      auto vec_data = new Vector<T>(static_cast<T *>(data_info.ptr), {data_info.shape[0]});
      auto vec_indices = new Vector<ssize_t>(static_cast<ssize_t *>(indices_info.ptr), {indices_info.shape[0]});
      auto vec_indptr = new Vector<ssize_t>(static_cast<ssize_t *>(indptr_info.ptr), {indptr_info.shape[0]});
      std::array<ssize_t, 2> shape_ = {*shape.data(0), *shape.data(1)};
      new(&matrix) csr_matrix<T>(*vec_data, *vec_indices, *vec_indptr, shape_);
    })
    .def_readonly("data", &csr_matrix<T>::data)
    .def_readonly("indices", &csr_matrix<T>::indices)
    .def_readonly("indptr", &csr_matrix<T>::indptr);
```

Now, I write a simple unit test in Python to make sure everything is working properly and I get the most baffling error

```py
x = sp.csr_matrix([
    [0, 0, 1, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [3, 0, 4, 0],
], dtype=np.float32)
cx = matrix.Float32CSRMatrix(x.data, x.indices, x.indptr, x.shape)
np.testing.assert_equal(x.data, np.asarray(cx.data, dtype=np.float32))
np.testing.assert_equal(x.indices, np.asarray(cx.indices, dtype=np.uint64))
np.testing.assert_equal(x.indptr, np.asarray(cx.indptr, dtype=np.uint64))  # fails here!
```

I throw a couple of prints after each line and this is the output

```
print(1, np.asarray(cx.data, dtype=np.float32), np.asarray(cx.indices, dtype=np.uint64), np.asarray(cx.indptr, dtype=np.uint64))
#  data         indices   indptr
- [1. 2. 3. 4.] [2 3 0 2] [0 2 2 4]  # original, python object
0 [1. 2. 3. 4.] [2 3 0 2] [0 2 2 4]  # after matrix.Float32CSRMatrix(...)
1 [1. 2. 3. 4.] [2 3 0 2] [0 2 2 4]  # after assert on data
2 [1. 2. 3. 4.] [2 3 0 2] [2 3 0 2]  # after assert on indices
# Fails at assert on indptr!
```

So somewhere, something changed the values of `indptr` into `indices`, and I have no clue what and where. What's even more baffling is that if I change the order of the asserts so that indptr is checked before indices, like this

```
np.testing.assert_equal(x.data, np.asarray(cx.data, dtype=np.float32))
np.testing.assert_equal(x.indptr, np.asarray(cx.indptr, dtype=np.uint64))
np.testing.assert_equal(x.indices, np.asarray(cx.indices, dtype=np.uint64))  # fails here!
```

then this is the output

```
- [1. 2. 3. 4.] [2 3 0 2] [0 2 2 4]
0 [1. 2. 3. 4.] [2 3 0 2] [0 2 2 4]
1 [1. 2. 3. 4.] [2 3 0 2] [0 2 2 4]
2 [1. 2. 3. 4.] [0 2 2 4] [0 2 2 4]
# Now fails at assert indices; we do the assert on indptr before, and it passes
```

So now, it's `indices` that are being overridden with `indptr`, and not the other way around. I've been banging my head against this wall for well over a day now and I have no clue what's going on. Object lifetime is not an issue, vectors are constructed at the start and destructed when the csr_matrix goes away. And I have pasted here **all** the relevant code, and I am not doing anything that might cause this.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is already done in `pybind11/eigen.h`, see https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/a54eab92d265337996b8e4b4149d9176c2d428a6/include/pybind11/eigen.h#L540-L598

Comment: I do not want to use Eigen; that's overkill for my use-case. Also, I want to learn how to do this, so I can apply it to things that can't be done with Eigen.

Comment: At least you can compare your implementation to what pybind11 does to Eigen and see difference in ptr, indices, etc.